# javascript remove parent div where particular class appears in hierarchy below

Tags: javascript, html

First time question on this site.  Sorry if I have failed the formatting test.

I am almost completely ignorant about javascript but I have been told I need it to solve this problem.  I have a page where there are multiple divs with the same class.  Each has a multi-level hierarchy beneath it.  I want to stop the parent displaying if any of its children contain a div of a particular class.  e.g.  In the following code I want to stop all divs with class of "classa" displaying if one of their direct or indirect children contains class of "classb draft".  So here, none of divb would display.

```
    <div id="diva" class="classa">
        <div id="divaa">
        </div>
        <div id="divab">
            <div id="divaba">
                <div id="divabaa"
                    <div id="divabaaa" class="classb">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divb" class="classa">
        <div id="divba">
        </div>
        <div id="divbb">
            <div id="divbba">
                <div id="divbbaa"
                    <div id="divbbaaa" class="classb draft">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing `div` in

```
<div id="divabaa"
```

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all the children with that class (`draft`). Then use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through all the matching elements to find the [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) div with `.classa` to set `display` property to `none`.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.classa .draft');
elements.forEach(function(el){
  el.closest('.classa').style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<div id="diva" class="classa">
    <div id="divaa">
    </div>
    <div id="divab">
        <div id="divaba">
            <div id="divabaa">
                <div id="divabaaa" class="classb">
                  Without Draft
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divs" class="classa">
    <div id="divba">
    </div>
    <div id="divbb">
        <div id="divbba">
            <div id="divbbaa">
                <div id="divbbaaa" class="classb draft">
                 Draft
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```